# How to manage network user process

Tags: vb.net, process

How can I connect to a network user process and manage it in vb.net?

Actually, I can only start a taskkill like this:

```
Process.Start("taskkill", "/S UC-PC109 /FI "USERNAME eq PC109" /PID 8324")
```

But I also need to check if program is executing and/or wait for program exit

Comment: `Process.Start` returns a `Process` object - use that to check for its status

Answer (score 0):

for local processes....

```
    Dim p As New Process()
    Dim ps As New ProcessStartInfo
    ps.FileName = "somefile.exe"

    p.StartInfo = ps
    p.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()
```

You can use getprocesses to get them from a remote PC

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunetly i tried to use process.kill() on a remote process, but the exception tell me that the functionality is not supported for a remote computer

Comment: you could use wmi to kill it remotely, once youve got the name or PID
http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/remoting/19019-remotely-ending-process.html

Answer (score 0):

`Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)` will return all the processes that are running in system with this name. So you can fetch all the process using this method of `Process Class` like this

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
```

Now if you have to terminate all the processes with this name then you can use bleow code

```
foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
                try 
                { 
                    proc.Kill(); 
                }
                catch (Exception exp) 
                {
                    //Log Exception.
                }
            }
```

or if you have to wait for any process then use this...

```
proc.WaitForExit(2000); //process is your process and 2000 is millisecond
```

**Note**: This code is written in C#, pls.